# Prometheus alert is that expr check for that last value?

Tags: alert, prometheus

currently, I have many checkpoints with label: cluster, service
when I have expr field in prometheus file like: up == 0, and in 1 minute, I have many new "up" value return from my endpoints, some fail, some success, is  that up == 0 only check the last value, or every single one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

`up` is an instant vector, so it'll be only the last one. If you wanted to check over a time period you could do for example `avg_over_time(up[5m]) < 0.5` to see if over half the scrapes failed in the last 5 minutes.